# How can i create a customizable SQL function in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, checkbox

Is it possible to create an extendable SQL query in Visual studio?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select geneID from Table3 where geneID in(" + filterdata + ")";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    con.Close();
}
```

Can this be extended to select any possible parameter from any possible tables using any possible conditions. I think it would look something like the following:

Select [Variable 1,Variable 2...] from [Table 1, Table2...] where [Condition1, Condition 2...]

The variables, tables and conditions in this case will be selected using a multitude of checkbox's. I want to incorporate any possible search into one button click.

Comment: Look up Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

Use sql joins ..Inside your commenttext like select a.row,b.rowtwo from tableone a inner join tabletwo b on a.row = b.row where a.row = your values

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.Format method

> Converts the value of objects to strings based on the formats specified and inserts them into another string.
>
> If you are new to the String.Format method, see the [Getting started with the String.Format method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting) section for a quick overview.

So you can use like that

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("Select {0} from {1} where {2}", columns, tables, conditions)
```